# How do I convert csv string to list in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy, pandas

I'm working with a csv file that has the following format:

```
"Id","Sequence"
3,"1,3,13,87,1053,28576,2141733,508147108,402135275365,1073376057490373,9700385489355970183,298434346895322960005291,31479360095907908092817694945,11474377948948020660089085281068730"
7,"1,2,1,5,5,1,11,16,7,1,23,44,30,9,1,47,112,104,48,11,1,95,272,320,200,70,13,1,191,640,912,720,340,96,15,1,383,1472,2464,2352,1400,532,126,17,1,767,3328,6400,7168,5152,2464,784,160,19,1,1535,7424"
8,"1,2,4,5,8,10,16,20,32,40,64,80,128,160,256,320,512,640,1024,1280,2048,2560,4096,5120,8192,10240,16384,20480,32768,40960,65536,81920,131072,163840,262144,327680,524288,655360,1048576,1310720,2097152"
11,"1,8,25,83,274,2275,132224,1060067,3312425,10997342,36304451,301432950,17519415551,140456757358,438889687625,1457125820233,4810267148324,39939263006825,2321287521544174,18610239435360217"
```

I'd like to read this into a data frame with the type of `df['Id']` to be integer-like and the type of `df['Sequence']` to be list-like.

I currently have the following kludgy code:

```
def clean(seq_string):
    return list(map(int, seq_string.split(',')))

# Read data
training_data_file = "data/train.csv"    
train = pd.read_csv(training_data_file)
train['Sequence'] = list(map(clean, train['Sequence'].values))
```

This appears to work, but I feel like the same could be achieved natively using pandas and numpy.

Does anyone have a recommendation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a [`converter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for the `Sequence` column:

> `converters`: `dict`, default `None`
>
> Dict of functions for converting
>   values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column
>   labels

```
train = pd.read_csv(training_data_file, converters={'Sequence': clean})
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thought it would be something simple like this. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This also works, except that the `Sequence` is list of string instead of list of int:

```
df = pd.read_csv(training_data_file)
df['Sequence'] = df['Sequence'].str.split(',')
```

To convert each element to int:

```
df = pd.read_csv(training_data_file)
df['Sequence'] = df['Sequence'].str.split(',').apply(lambda s: list(map(int, s)))
```

Comment: And if I wanted to convert it to a list of int, I could just append `.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`, right?

Comment: It seems that the command has been deprecated, need to loop through the list and convert manually. But this gets back to original solution somehow.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use `literal_eval` from the `ast` module. `literal_eval` evaluates the string as input to the Python interpreter and should give you back the list as expected.

```
def clean(x):
    return literal_eval(x)

train = pd.read_csv(training_data_file, converters={'Sequence': clean})
```