# pandas - convert string into list of strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv

I have this 'file.csv' file to read with pandas:

```
Title|Tags
T1|"[Tag1,Tag2]"
T1|"[Tag1,Tag2,Tag3]"
T2|"[Tag3,Tag1]"
```

using

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='|')
```

the output is:

```
  Title              Tags
0    T1       [Tag1,Tag2]
1    T1  [Tag1,Tag2,Tag3]
2    T2       [Tag3,Tag1]
```

I know that the column `Tags` is a full string, since:

```
In [64]: df['Tags'][0][0]
Out[64]: '['
```

I need to read it as a list of strings like `["Tag1","Tag2"]`. I tried the solution provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171072/how-do-i-convert-csv-string-to-list-in-pandas) question but no luck there, since I have the `[` and `]` characters that actually mess up the things.

The expecting output should be:

```
In [64]: df['Tags'][0][0]
Out[64]: 'Tag1'
```

Comment: I asked a question similar to this before, you can see the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529483/python-convert-string-list-to-list

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can split the string manually:

```
>>> df['Tags'] = df.Tags.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(','))
>>> df.Tags[0]
['Tag1', 'Tag2']
```

Comment: Or apply it on load...`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='|', converters={'Tags': lambda x: x[1:-1].split(',')})`

Comment: @JonClements, `converters={'Tags': lambda x: x[1:-1].split(',')}` just saved me so much headache. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 19):

You could use the inbuilt `ast.literal_eval`, it works for tuples as well as lists

```py
import ast
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"mytuples": ["(1,2,3)"]})

print(df.iloc[0,0])
# >> '(1,2,3)'

df["mytuples"] = df["mytuples"].apply(ast.literal_eval)

print(df.iloc[0,0])
# >> (1,2,3)
```

---

EDIT: `eval` should be avoided! If the the string being evaluated is `os.system(‘rm -rf /’)` it will start deleting all the files on your computer ([here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)).  For `ast.literal_eval` the string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)).  Thanks @TrentonMcKinney :)

Comment: best solution, the other solutions did not worked for me

Answer (score 15):

I think you could use the json module.

```
import json
import pandas

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='|')
df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```

So this will load your dataframe as before, then apply a lambda function to each of the items in the `Tags` column. The lambda function calls `json.loads()` which converts the string representation of the list to an actual list.

Comment: I think this is a better solution, less prone to errors! Also, note that you can pass `json.loads` directly as an `apply` parameter: `df['Tags'].apply(json.loads)`

Answer (score 11):

Or

```
df.Tags=df.Tags.str[1:-1].str.split(',').tolist()
```

Comment: @WeNToBen - nice solution. Care to expand on it a little bit? why do we need `str[1:-1]`, why is it not `str[0:-1]`? (for me both yield the same result by the way). Also, if `split()` already creates a list, why do we explicitly call `tolist()`?

Comment: @zerohedge cause you want to remove the "[" at the beginning and "]" at the end

Comment: thanks. and why `tolist()` after `split()` (which itself creates a list, no?)

Comment: @zerohedge ah , that one I need to remove ,you are right

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the string to a list using `strip` and `split`.

```
df_out = df.assign(Tags=df.Tags.str.strip('[]').str.split(','))

df_out.Tags[0][0]
```

Output:

```
'Tag1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `df['Tags']` appears to be a list of strings. If you print that list you should get `["[tag1,tag2]","[Tag1,Tag2,Tag3]","[Tag3,Tag1]"]` this is why when you call the first element of the first element you're actually getting the first single character of the string, rather than what you want.

You either need to parse that string afterward. Performing something like

```
df['Tags'][0] = df['Tags'][0].split(',')
```

But as you saw in your cited example this will give you a list that looks like

```
in: df['Tags'][0][0] 
out: '[tag1'`
```

What you need is a way to parse the string editing out multiple characters. You can use a simple regex expression to do this. Something like:

```
 import re
 df['Tags'][0] = re.findall(r"[\w']+", df['Tags'][0])
 print(df['Tags'][0][0])
```

will print:

```
 'tag1'
```

Using the other answer involving Pandas converters you might write a converter like this:

```
 def clean(seq_string):
      return re.findall(r"[\w']+", seq_string)
```

If you don't know regex, they can be quite powerful, but also unpredictable if you're not sure on the content of your input strings. The expression used here `r"[\w']+"` will match any common word character alpha-numeric and underscores and treat everything else as a point for `re.findall` to split the list at.