# Convert a single string inside list into multiple string inside that same list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, nlp, data-preprocessing

I have a dataframe which consists of a column having tags as

```
tags
------------
['tag1' 'tag2']
['tag1']
['tag5' 'tag3' 'tag6']
```

How to get the dataframe in following format?

```
    tags
    ------------
    ['tag1','tag2']
    ['tag1']
    ['tag5','tag3','tag6']
```

While viewing the single row:

```
print(df['tags'][0][0])
>>> "'tag1' 'tag2'"
print(df['tags'][0][0][0]
>>> "'"
```

I tried the following method:

```
def Convert(string): 
    li = list(string.split(" ")) 
    return li 
str1 = Convert(df1['tags'][0][0])
print(str1)
>>> ["'tag1'", "'tag2'"]
```

**Method2** This also didn't work to me.

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(df['tags'][0][0])
>>>'tag1tag2'
```

**Question2** I want to count the total occurrence of tags and `df['tags'].value_counts()` doesn't work. It either takes the whole list as count their occurrence or if i modify the list then it will take the character count.

Comment: Your objective is not clear to me. Do you want to split strings of the form " \'tag1\' \'tag2\' "?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas - convert string into list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758646/pandas-convert-string-into-list-of-strings)

Comment: @JanAlexander I have a list say `list1 = ['tag1' 'tag2']` and i want to access the list item tag1 and tag2. But the list is actually in form `list1 = ["'tag1' 'tag2"']` . By accessing the list item, i mean in the format `list1 = ['tag1','tag2']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```py
list1 = ["'tag1' 'tag2'"]
result = [w.strip("'") for w in list1[0].split(' ')]
print(f'converted\n{list1}\nto\n{result}')
```