# Splitting objects of different lengths in panda series

Tags: python, pandas, list, object

Python/pandas beginner here.

I have a pandas series (column of a larger df), what looks like this:

```
0                                   ['0344010000122413']
1                                   ['0344010000132886']
2                                   ['0344010000021642']
3      ['0344010000010731', '0344010000010732', '0344...
4                                   ['0344010000025264']
Name: NUMPOINTS, Length: 271, dtype: object
```

The length of each NUMPPOINT = 16. The number of NUMPOINTS per row differs from 0 to ±100.

As you can see, the dtype of the series is an object. The goal is that I want to convert each row in this series into real lists and the numbers to integers, but this cannot happen because of the dtype and the `['` and `']`. The variable length per row makes it not possible to use certain functions.

I used `df['NUMPOINTS'] = df.NUMPOINTS.apply(lambda x: x[2:-2].split(','))` but that only works for rows with 1 NUMPOINT.

I used the `df['NUMPOINTS'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')` function, but this 'sticks' the objects together. For example, index 3 gives:

```
3      0344010000010731034401000001073203440100000107...
```

Then converting to integers gives an error.

I used the solutions in this question [pandas - convert string into list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758646/pandas-convert-string-into-list-of-strings) but did not do the job either.
Am I missing something here?

EDIT:
Trying https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely updated answer gives me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-374-5f4f43cc7fc1> in <module>()
      1 from ast import literal_eval
      2 df["NUMPOINTS"] = df["NUMPOINTS"].apply(
----> 3     lambda x: [
      4         int(value) for value in (literal_eval(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
      5     ]

2 frames
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-374-5f4f43cc7fc1> in <listcomp>(.0)
      2 df["NUMPOINTS"] = df["NUMPOINTS"].apply(
      3     lambda x: [
----> 4         int(value) for value in (literal_eval(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
      5     ]
      6 )

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "0344010000010731'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `ast.literal_eval` and then `int()` inside list comprehension:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df["NUMPOINTS"] = df["NUMPOINTS"].apply(
    lambda x: [int(value) for value in literal_eval(x)]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                            NUMPOINTS
0                   [344010000122413]
1                   [344010000132886]
2                   [344010000021642]
3  [344010000010731, 344010000010732]
4                   [344010000025264]
```

---

EDIT:

If you have strings/lists in your column:

```py
df["NUMPOINTS"] = df["NUMPOINTS"].apply(
    lambda x: [
        int(value.strip("'")) for value in (literal_eval(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
    ]
)
print(df)
```

Comment: This gives me this error: ```ValueError: malformed node or string: ```

Comment: @QB-science Do you have `NaN` values in the column? Do you have some strings other than `[ ... ]` in the column?

Comment: No ``` NaN``` but there are some rows with only ```[]```

Comment: @QB-science That shouldn't be a problem. Edit your question and put full error traceback there (with correct formatting).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that still does not do the job. I updated the error traceback.

Comment: @QB-science Try `int(value.strip("'"))` I updated my answer. But really, seems you have "dirty" data in your column...

Comment: Can I also use the ``` int(value.strip("'")``` with an extra ```.strip``` for spaces?

Comment: @QB-science Yes, change your values the way it's correct integer - without spaces, `'` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
```

You can also do with `map()` and `pd.eval()` method:

```
df['NUMPOINTS']=df['NUMPOINTS'].map(lambda x: [int(y.lstrip('0').rstrip("'")) for y in (pd.eval(x) if type(x).__name__=='str' else x)])
```

Now if you print `df` you will get:

```
                            NUMPOINTS
0                   [344010000122413]
1                   [344010000132886]
2                   [344010000021642]
3  [344010000010731, 344010000010732]
4                   [344010000025264]
```

Comment: This solution gives me this Syntax Error: ```File "<unknown>", line 1
    [0 344010000122413 ]
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the updated answer gives me ``` File "<unknown>", line 1
    [0 344010000122413 ]
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax ```