# How to access cell values as complete strings not each character separately in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can i acces each category in categories?

|  | Categories |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [' Backend ', ' Python '] |
| 2 | [' Big Data ', ' Python '] |

I tried to input print(df["categories"][0][1])
My output is '
I want it to be ' Backend '

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas - convert string into list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758646/pandas-convert-string-into-list-of-strings)

Comment: You might want `df.at[1, 'Categories'][0]`